# Date of Weekday of the week which contain original date

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want the date of Weekday=friday of the week which contain original date

I had tried with the below coding but it is not working :-

```
Nsdate currDate;(currDate can be date)
int dayofweek; // Detect the day of week
NSString *Start_date = @"13/nov/2014";
                    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
                    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:currDate];
 NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* comp = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:Startdate]; dayofweek=[comp weekday];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
 NSDate *Startdate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
Startdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:Start_date];
NSDate *fetchdate=[self firstDayOfWeekFromDate:Startdate];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *stringFromDate1 = [formatter stringFromDate:fetchdate];
NSString *trimmedString=[stringFromDate1 substringFromIndex:MAX((int)[stringFromDate1 length]-2, 0)];
NSString *trimmedString1=[stringFromDate substringFromIndex:MAX((int)[stringFromDate1 length]-2, 0)];
if([trimmedString1 isEqualToString:trimmedString]){
     NSlog(@"YES IT IS DAY OF WEEK");
}


//***************************function

- (NSDate *)firstDayOfWeekFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* comps = [calendar components:NSYearForWeekOfYearCalendarUnit |NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    [comps setWeekday:dayofweek]; // 2: monday
    return [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  You want Tuesday but you want Friday?  What?

Comment: Are you saying for any given date, you want to know the date of the Friday that is in the week of the original date?

Comment: @Flexicoder Yes.. I want the date of Weekday=firday of the week which contain original  date

Comment: @iosdeveloper why have you asked this again on a different account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down into steps. There's absolutely no reason to do it all in a single function.

I'm assuming you want the same Friday next year. (from your last question that you deleted)

First you need to get the same date in a year's time.

```
- (NSDate *)dateOneYearFromDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
    components.year = 1;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
}
```

Then you need to work out what day that date is...

```
- (NSInteger)dayOfWeekFromDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    return components.weekday;
}
```

Then you need to find the Friday from that date...

```
- (NSDate *)fridayFromWeekOfDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSInteger friday = 6;
    NSInteger dayOfWeekFromDate = [self dayOfWeekFromDate:date];

    NSInteger difference = friday - dayOfWeekFromDate;

    NSDateComponents *components = [NSDateComponents new];
    components.day = difference;

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    return [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:date options:0];
}
```

Make each step a small step...

Now you can do this...

```
- (void)someFunction
{
    NSDate *someFriday = // this is your original date...

    NSDate *oneYearLater = [self dateOneYearFromDate:someFriday];

    NSDate *fridayOneYearFromNow = [self fridayFromWeekOfDate:oneYearLater];
}
```

Comment: The answer which you posted give me the date after 1year.What i need is i will input two date. 1)Original date 2)Some selected date. Then i will check whether the selected date is the date of the Friday(weekday of the original date)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should get you started... (coded blind/not tested)

```
NSDate * currentDate = [NSDate date];

CFAbsoluteTime at = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
CFTimeZoneRef tz = CFTimeZoneCopySystem();
SInt32 WeekdayNumber = CFAbsoluteTimeGetDayOfWeek(at, tz);
int currentDayOfTheWeek = (int)WeekdayNumber;
if(currentDayOfTheWeek == 5) {
    //Its Friday!
    return currentDate;
} else {
    return [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((60 * 60 * 24) * (5 - currentDayOfTheWeek)]; 
}
```

Comment: It's dangerous to use 60*60*24 to mean one day as it's not always true. You should always use NSCalendar and its functions to add days, weeks, months, etc... onto dates. This is stated in Apple's WWDC videos too.